# .odm to .mp3 Audiobook Converter

Tags: windows, gratis, mp3, file-converter, audiobook

So through my library, they have a subscription to an audiobook provider where I checked out a few books. I then went to their download section and under the book I checked out, it had a button that said, "Download (MP3 Audiobook)"; however, when I clicked the button it downloaded a .odm file instead of a .mp3 file. So, I'm looking for software that is able to convert .odm files to .mp3 file(s). I would like the software to meet these requirements,

- Gratis
- Compatible with Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .odm file is not an actual audio book it is an XML media file that defines information about the audio book and where to download it from.

The application to open it is [Overdrive Media](https://app.overdrive.com/) which is a free application available for multiple platforms including Windows 8/10.  Once you have that application you may find that it downloads the actual audio files in MP3 or another format that you can convert to MP3 or you may be happy enough just using that application.

The application can [convert files to MP3 for playing on external media players](http://help.overdrive.com/customer/portal/articles/1481070-how-to-transfer-audiobooks-to-an-mp3-player-using-overdrive-for-windows).

Comment: Overdrive died. Is there any other option?

Comment: @Bob is correct that the desktop Overdrive software is no longer available.  The replacement for Overdrive is [Libby](https://www.overdrive.com/apps/libby#GetTheApp) a possible way to convert requires a longer answer that a comment so adding a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

With the demise of the Overdrive desktop software it is no longer possible to use that to convert `.odf` files into `.mp3` with it. The replacement for `Overdrive` is [Libby](https://www.overdrive.com/apps/libby/) or [Sora](https://www.overdrive.com/apps/sora/) neither of which are for the desktop.

An alternative workflow using free software *so far untested* might be:

- Download and install the Libby App for your platform from https://libbyapp.com/ *You will need a library card!*
- 
- Install Python 3 for your platform from [Python.org](https://www.python.org/)
- Install [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) for your platform *make a note of where it is installed then add it to your path variable*.
- Use the command `python3 -m pip install git+https://git@github.com/ping/odmpy.git@0.7.5` to install V0.7.5 of `odmpy` *(Miss out the `@0.7.5` for the latest version of `odmpy`)*
- Use `odmpy` to checkout & download the audiobook with the experimental `merge` option - this should download all of the chapters and process the file into a single `.mp3` file.
- When finished "return" the audiobook to the library.